# How to automatically load profile in IPython/Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In earlier versions of IPython it was possible to load a specific profile by

```
ipython notebook --profile=my_profile
```

so that I can include things like `autoreload` in my_profile.

Since using `IPython 4.0.1` (Jupyter actually) I'm getting the

```
[W 09:21:32.868 NotebookApp] Unrecognized alias: '--profile=my_profile', it will probably have no effect.
```

warning, and the profile is not loaded. Have you come across a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

In Jupyter create a kernel for each profile.

Find the kernels directory under the jupyter configuration directory `{jupyter configuration}/kernels` (on my Mac this is `$HOME/Library/Jupyter/kernels`):

```
$ mkdir profile-x-kernel
$ cat << EOF > profile-x-kernel/kernel.json
{                                
    "display_name": "Profile X (Python 3)",
    "language": "python3",          
    "env": { },                              
    "argv": [ "python3", "-m", "ipykernel", "--profile", "profile_x", "-f", "{connection_file}" ]
}
EOF
```

Then you can select the kernel from the kernel menu in Jupyter, without having to restart the whole notebook server.